# AppFabric velocity as a state server

Tags: caching, appfabric, stateserver

Is anybody using Windows AppFabric Server for out of process state management?

Any feedback, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of application you want to use AppFabric Caching for?  Its Azure integration is currently only in beta (with release slated for Q2 2011 (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appfabricctp/thread/67ea9f1a-c846-4da0-9c49-ecde1e775cae)), so you probably won't see many people using it for production purposes.

Comment: If you are referring to Windows AppFabric Server please modify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AppFabric Caching.  We tried this and it appeared to work, was easy to setup etc.  There are some very strange settings when setting up the cache about peristance which need to be read carefully.

Our issue was on two server we installed IIS and Appfabric Caching and told app to try the local one first.  When we went into production is just started to fail.  It appears that with only two servers there is a lead server which if it goes down things stop working, we read that if needed to scale to 3 or more servers to get the behaviour we wanted.  Not an option when just gone live and not working so we switched to SQL server for now while we look at nCache and ScaleOut and Memchached

The other issue is that caching and session state are not the same animal, if you loose your cache it should not be the end of the world just put it back together, we need to keep session state for the lotted time period at all costs.